# (apply qe) does not eliminate all quantifiers at once?

Tags: z3, quantifiers

I am asking Z3 to do quantifier elimination in the UFLIA theory, using the SMTLIB 2 interface. So I assert a formula with 21 existentially quantified variables, of them seven are integer and 14 are Boolean. Then I do `(apply qe)` and Z3 returns a goal that still contains nine existentially quantified variables, named `(x!1 Int)`, `(x!14 Int)` and `(x!14!1 Int)` to `(x!14!7 Int)`. Does that mean the `qe` tactic does not eliminate all quantifiers at once?

If I do `(assert qe)` twice, the goal stays the same except for the quantified variables renamed. I tried `(repeat qe)`, but that returns `unsupported`, also setting the `:eliminate-variables-as-block` parameter to true does not change anything.

However, if I take the quantified formula from the goal, assert it on its own and do `assert qe` again, Z3 eliminates the remaining quantifiers as I wanted to.

See the link below for the formula, is there some magic I need to do to have Z3 eliminate all quantifiers at once?

https://gist.github.com/chsticksel/edeb350fa4474713f3df#file-apply-qe-does-not-eliminate-all-quantifiers-at-once-smt

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the bug report. It has been fixed now in the unstable branch.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, but I have another one. Running the current unstable Z3 on https://gist.github.com/chsticksel/a68d93d5f6d6163a3457 returns a goal with quantifiers again.